# Apache Empty response Diognosis

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, connection

My server gives empty response randomly. This is about four weeks that I cant figure out what is the problem.
I will try my best to give you extensive information about my problem.

sever specs: centos 6, apache webserver,mysql database,php

1. The chance to get an empty response from server goes up when server traffic is higher

2. It takes a little time for sever to give out an empty response (about 2-10 seconds)

3.when I encounter this problem It lasts 20 seconds to 4 minute.

4. Server gives this empty response to specific ips. If I load website from another Ip, Website loads without any problem.

5. I sent a ticket to server provider (they are re-sellers of hetzner) and they say there is nothing wrong with network. (But I think maybe there is a bandwidth limit that is reaching out or some kind of firewall)

6. I turned of iptables and the problem persisted.

7. during the problem sometime it takes about 10 seconds for server to give out the empty response. During this 10 seconds if I restart httpd server. It gives out empty response right away.

8.I installed nginx beside apache on port 800 when server encounters this problem and gives out empty response on port 80. It still has the problem on port 800. and gives out connection reset.

9. server load is below 1

10. I can still connect to the server through ssh port while server gives out empty response

11. there is nothing in error log

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in the Chrome developer tools? Are there any errors? 10 seconds delays could be database problems, PHP, DNS.  Eliminate possible bugs in your application before looking at network.

Comment: Is it PHP appiication? Do you have enabled php error_log? What is returned http status code?

Comment: I don't think it is relevant to database,because it gives empty response for everything even images.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks that a timeout occurs somewhere in your application due to high server load or some other reason. This timeout isn't handled correctly, and it returns an empty page to Apache.

This timeout could happen with a database query, application code, with an external request etc. A database problem can also cause this error, if the application doesn't handle the problem correctly. The fact that nothing appears doesn't exclude that from the possible causes.

Without knowing the details of your application architecture, it is impossible to give a more precise answer.

Comment: But I installed nginx on seprate port. (just requesting and static image) and it gave me connection reset. I have written my application myself.

Comment: Maybe your nginx isn't installed correctly, or some firewall prevents access to port 800. I am quite sure that this nginx problem isn't related to the main issue at all. You need to ask about the nginx issue in a separate question.

Comment: I installed nginx for debugging purposes. nginx  on port 800 works fine when there no problem on port 80. the problem occurs simultanously

Comment: OK, then it is definitely your application that has the issue. What is the error message in nginx error.log? Usually it is located in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: there is nothing in it. don't you think it is something outside sever?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that would indicate it being a network problem. Implement logging in your application, where you write logging information in different places of the application with timestamps and connection information, and then you can debug where in your application the timeout occurs.

Comment: thank you. I will do that and i will comment here. I will wait for your answer.

Comment: I tested it right now. I tried a url like this http://domain/testserver1, when problem happens there is nothing even in access log. the uniqe url that tested does not add on access log.

Comment: This is not logging inside the application. Logging is when you open a log file when the application starts, write the starting time and remote IP of the request, then you write log entries in different spots in the application. You also put an entry to the log file when the application finishes processing the request. This way you can have a detailed view of what happens inside your application, if it dies before correctly finishing the request, if some part takes too long to process etc.